# Book about poor people boycotting rich

Tags: identification-request

A book I am looking for is about how one day all poor people stopped working. All shops closed and rich people were left on their own - their cars would break down, no food at home - and all the poor were planning this and prepared with lots of food.

I think the book had many dystopian stories in it - one was about a remotely controlled revolver, another about invisibility.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_strike ?

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please look through the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) to see if it jogs your memory, and if so, please [edit] further details into your question. For example, was this a novel or a collection of short stories? Were there illustrations? Approximately when did you read it? What language was it written in, and are you aware if it was a translation or not? Where did you read the book? etc.